# Migrate entirely to HTTPS to allow cookies to be set by same-site subresources

Tags: .net, angular, api, http, https

Migrate entirely to HTTPS to allow cookies to be set by same-site subresources
A cookie was not set by an insecure origin in a secure context. Because this cookie would have been set across schemes on the same site, it was blocked. This behavior enhances the SameSite attribute’s protection of user data from request forgery by network attackers.
Resolve this issue by migrating your site (as defined by the eTLD+1) entirely to HTTPS. It is also recommended to mark the cookie with the Secure attribute if that is not already the case.

I added in my .net core webapi in startup class

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
            });
```

but i still have such error. How i can update my angular 13 app from http to https
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIemR.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have also set on my server the secure policy

```
        options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
        options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.None;
```

And check om the firefox if it works because chrome blocks cookies sent from https to http or reverse

If you just need to do it for your local dev environment, You can retain the old behavior for cookies in chrome by disabling

```
chrome://flags/#same-site-by-default-cookies
chrome://flags/#cookies-without-same-site-must-be-secure

I have to support legacy http clients, but if I make https:// origin secure , I can't set cookie from http, more over I can't access this cookie from http, my goal is to have SameSite=None, Secure on http and not secure on http:// origin, any ideas, instead of establishing protests near google office ?
```